# Mochajs test keep running when using async/await

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm using mochajs to test an express API. I have some async functions because I query a database. I read in this [github issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2407#issuecomment-467917882) that using async / await should work. However, the test keeps running and I have to manually close the process regardless that the promise is resolved as can be seen in the `console.log`.

Surprisingly, it stops if I only run a previous test that is using the same async / await pattern. The only difference is that, in the second, there is another await in the function tested, but it is also resolved properly.

```
       it('Returns error when token is not correct', async () => {
            let result = await addSciStudy({token: 'fake'})
            console.log(result)
            expect(result).to.have.key('error')
        });

// { error: 'Token is not correct, please contact the administrator' }
```

Here is the test (line 12): https://github.com/icra/snappAPI-v2/blob/main/tests/test-add-sci-study.js

And here the tested function: https://github.com/icra/snappAPI-v2/blob/main/lib/add-sci-study.js

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the tested function there was a call to another function that queries a database. Mochajs was waiting for the connection to close to stop the tests. So, I created a function to close the connection that I can import in the test scripts:

```
const closeDB = function(){
    connection.end()
    return 0
}
```

The problem is that when the connection is closed, then is no longer opened. So, if other tests where querying the database, they failed. What I did is to create a fake test at the end that close the connection once all test have run:

```
describe('test something', () => {
    describe('all the test here', () => {
        <all tests here>
    });
    describe('close DB connection', () => {
        it('close DB connection', () => {
            closeDB()
        });
    });
});
```

The only drawback is that when one test is run interactively, the test must still be manually stopped. But it stops when tests are run programatically, which is important if you want to integrate them in a bash script to test before deploy, for instance.